# Why are some Unicode characters invisible in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, unicode

I've been doing some tricks with Emacs Unicode support, and for the most part it works great. However, not all Unicode characters seem to display, even when they are in the font. For instance:

> → ‽ ←   There is supposed to be an interrobang there

The above (assuming it gets rendered properly) has normal ASCII chars, a couple of Unicode arrows, and a Unicode INTERROBANG (a very useful glyph that needs more widespread use). However, the Interrobang will not show up in Emacs no matter what. I'm displaying in DejaVu Sans which definitely has the right glyph. OpenOffice can open the file and shows the glyph. But I can't get Emacs to show it no matter what I try.

This is Emacs 24.1.1 on the Mac.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the [unicode-fonts](https://github.com/rolandwalker/unicode-fonts) package. You can install it through `M-x package-install unicode-fonts`, and then put the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(require 'unicode-fonts)
(unicode-fonts-setup)
```

Most unicode fonts now work for me. Some characters like BEER MUG still won't display for me though. I'm also using emacs (v24.3 installed using homebrew) on a mac.

EDIT:
Apparently, some symbols still won't display because of [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906621/emacs-font-setup-for-displaying-unicode-characters-in-osx).

Comment: Under Windows, DejaVu Sans Mono was displaying the unicode chars as expected, but no way Courier New or Consolas would display them (that's why I've noticed the problem). Solved with your answer, and also, I confirm that Emacs on Win is not affected by the same bug (as clearly described on the bug link).

Comment: Doesn't work for me: this character `` still won't show up in Emacs.

Comment: Alright, so what worked for me is updating to the in-development Emacs version 29.0.50.150941. Now the unicode character shows up properly even though I don't have `unicode-fonts` package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade emacs to version >= 28
2. Install a font on your system that supports these glyphs (eg. one of the [NerdFonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts))
3. Configure emacs to use this as the default frame font in your `.emacs` eg.  like this `(set-frame-font "FiraCode Nerd Font 12" nil t)`

Comment: *Upgrade emacs to version >= 28* This question was asked over 9 years ago, and I don't think this **update** suggestion will help future users with same issue.